# Show default notification bar in Android

Tags: java, android, eclipse, adt

I have searched a lot over the internet and could'n find an answer.

I am working on a launcher project and on a **click of a button**, I want to launch default **notification bar** . Is there any **API**.

Comment: Have you tried going through any tutorials yet?

Comment: you want notification bar to slide down on click of button ?

Answer (score 0):

you can implement the android default notification using the below code. you can customize.

```
// Invoking the default notification service
    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
            this);

    mBuilder.setContentTitle("ur titlw");
    mBuilder.setContentText("ur content");
    mBuilder.setTicker("ur sticker");
    mBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.uricon);

    // Increase notification number every time a new notification arrives
    mBuilder.setNumber(++numMessagesOne);

    // Creates an explicit intent for an Activity in your app
    Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, ur activity where this notification shout appear);
    resultIntent.putExtra("notificationId", "test");

    // This ensures that navigating backward from the Activity leads out of
    // the app to Home page
    TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);

    // Adds the back stack for the Intent
    stackBuilder.addParentStack(ur activity where it returns when click on the notification);

    // Adds the Intent that starts the Activity to the top of the stack
    stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);
    PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT // can only be used once
            );
    // start the activity when the user clicks the notification text
    mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);

    myNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    // pass the Notification object to the system
    myNotificationManager.notify(notificationIdOne, mBuilder.build());
```

I hope this will be useful.